# How to get Logitech M305 wheel tilting to work as forward/backward?

Tags: 10.10, mouse

I have the mouse specified in the Title. At the moment when I tilt the wheel left/right it works as horizontal scrolling (which I do not use at all). I would like it to work as backward/forward buttons (for example in Firefox).

For Windows there are drivers which allow these events' mapping to be changed. I haven't found any drivers for Linux. Is it possible to change it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one, and afaik, the best way to make use of the tilt buttons (and various other buttons on many Logitech Mice) is to use btnx, which is in the repos.

I set my M305 tilts to control+page down/up, which handles tab shifting in many applications, but you could set it to whatever keystroke in FF goes back and forward.

There is also a closed source program, [HIDPoint](http://www.hidpoint.com/) which claims to mimic Setpoint, but I haven't really tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great way around. Works perfectly :)